# play and record audio from background app for audio visualizer

Tags: ios, swift

im trying to build an audio visualizer that records audio from streaming service playing in the background such as spotify or apple music.

```
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
```

will keep the music playing however, the volume is significantly reduced. Is there an AVAudioSession option that keep background audio playing without reducing volume?

Comment: did u get the solution mate?